# IPython NB output formatting changed templates need old?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I was producing PDF output using the basic article default which I quite liked, but now the format has changed.. How can I get the old tex template? The old format had right justified title author etc at the top the new format has only the title at the top center. further the current template does not space between paragraphs in the MD cells and the old one did it.

Any help appreciated.. I am sending some stuff out today I hope..

Comment: Would what you search be [here](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert-examples) ?

Comment: looked at that, can't tell, no real description or usage doc and the code does not help much in determining...

Comment: more specially, the old "article" class should be [this one](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert-examples/blob/master/sphinx_class/latex_sphinx_article.tplx) the lack of doc is due to the fact that nbconvert is still "in motion" on master the `--template=<path to your template>` flag should work.

Comment: Looks like that should be the one :-) mmm tried, 1) cloned the nbconvert-examples project to my home directory tried to use a modified "nocode template" and can't seem to get the directory syntax to find the new nb-convert templates so ((*- extends '../nbconvert-examples/sphinx_class/latex_sphinx_article.tplx' -*)) give me template not found have tried ~/nb... and ~/tom/nb  etc... no luck ideas?

Comment: FWIW if I do this to invoke vim on the file from the same directory I have the "nocode" tpl in VIM works fine tom@tom-sam:~/Downloads$ vim ../nbconvert-examples/sphinx_class/latex_sphinx_article.tplx

Comment: IIRC you need to set jinja search path somewhere explicitely (question of security) or put the template in cwd then (cwd is in search path). I'll try to write a blog post and doc, but API will again change before 2.0 ...

Comment: Got it many thanks you want to create an answer?

Comment: If I write an answer it will be too vague. Once I have blog post about that, I might post it here with a shorter explanation. (or you can answer to yourself if you had it to work)